# SwiftUI VideoPlayer isn't playing .3gp files in iOS 16.1

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to play a remote media file with .3gp extension with SwiftUI's VideoPlayer and AVPlayer.
But it always starts in muted mode. and nothing playes.

Following is my code.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var player = AVPlayer()
    
    @State var isPresentingAsSheet: Bool = false
    
    let url: String = "https://www.domw.com/path/to/file/abjDV17073062108598.3gp"
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        .onAppear {
            if let url = URL(string: url) {
                player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                player.play()
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            player.pause()
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it shows in simulator iOS 16.1

[image]

But .m4a files are working perfectly fine.

Can you help me figure out what's wrong with .3gp files. with SwiftUI VideoPlayer

Comment: The url of 3gp that you added is invalid... There is no video exists...

Comment: iOS supports various video formats and codecs, but not all codecs within the .3gp container might be supported. Ensure the video codec used in your .3gp file is compatible with iOS. Typically, H.264 (AVC) video and AAC audio codecs have the broadest support on iOS devices.
Please provide valid URL also